# Optimize nested recursions

Tags: c, recursion

I'm working on an interpreter, internal implementation sometimes requires recursion between evaluation functions, the concern is that I may sometimes need to perform several thousand recursions to satisfy a task, but the program obviously overflows the stack.

My implementation follows the following scheme:

```
void compute(Program program) {
    // Evaluate operations by calling specifics function...
    for (int i = 0; i < program.op_nbr; i++)
        eval_operation(&program.operations[i]);
}

void eval_operation(Operation op) {
    // Evaluate the operation
    switch (op->kind) {
        ...
        case Something: return eval_thing(&op->thing);
        ...
    }
}

void eval_thing(Thing thing) {
    for (int i = 0; i < thing.op_nbr; i++)
        eval_operation(&thing.operations[i]);
}
```

The scheme is indicative, I would like to know how to allow the program to perform more recursion according to this function call model, so:

- `compute` loop and call `eval_operation` for each operation ;
- `eval_operation` evaluate the given operation, if this is the operation kind `thing` then it calls `eval_thing` ;
- `eval_thing` call `eval_operation` for each operation that the "thing" contains.

I hope you understand the concept and anticipate what may happen: `eval_thing` can call itself several times (depending on the input), so I get a stack overflow if it happens too many times; logic, I know the limits of recursion in C, but I know that there are also optimizations, like tail optimization, but I don't think it is applicable to my problem; so my question is how to achieve more recursion, or even an infinity if possible (I can only do 1K as an example).

Could the fact that these functions are `void` and that passing by parameter is done via pointers be easier to solve this problem?

PS: By "nested recursions" I mean the fact that recursion is not performed directly inside the function itself, but via a call according to a for loop, typically:

```
void foo() {
    return bar();
}

void bar() {
    return foo();
}
```

Comment: I find this strange. Recursion for an interperter has a relation with the complexity of the program to be interpreted, and that is often not that much. For example, some nested loops in a function. So if Thing is an object, a nested data structrure will go maybe 3 deep, and an operation maybe 5 to 10, giving you a depth of maybe 30, which should not cause a stack overflow. I think there is something wrong in your model of the interpreter.

Comment: Ah... In fact, I have in my language to interpret "functions" operations (`thing` would represent them here, so a list of operation to evaluate). If I want to recursion with the functions of the language to interpret, I would have to evaluate the body as many times as this one is called. I had tested with the factorial (recursive) function, which runs until it reaches 0, and, as in C, the number of recursions was therefore limited. Actually, I don't see how else to do it.

Comment: Every time after you have evaluated the body, your recursion is zero for that function. So there may be thousands of recursions, but they are never deep.

Comment: Okay, but then do you have any idea where my stack overflow problem comes from then? This only happens when there are recursive functions to evaluate (after some recursions of course).

Comment: Also in C you get a stack overflow if the recursion is too deep, so why not in your interpreter?

Comment: One help can be to watch out that you do not copy whole things onto the stack and use pointers instead. Your example above seems to copy whole things.

Comment: I see, thank you. I do indeed pass pointers, but also whole things. I'll see what I can do about it.